# json_encode with mysql content and umlauts in utf-8

Tags: php, mysql, json, utf-8, diacritics

i feel my beard growing while trying to find out the Problem here.

Basic the Problem is, that Umlauts/Special Signs äöß ... don't work. I guess everyone is sick and tired of that questions but all the solutions found online don't seem to work.

Im having utf-8 content in a utf-8 Mysql Database. I feel the Problem ist somewhere in the Database connection but i just can't figure out.

> character_set_client    utf8
>   character_set_connection  utf8
>   character_set_database   utf8
>   character_set_filesystem  binary
>   character_set_results   utf8
>   character_set_server   latin1
>   character_set_system   utf8

Im not sure if the problem is the latin1 for character_set_server because im not into that mysql stuff. I also dont know how to change cause i can't access the mysql server's config files.

Whatever is confusing me, that if i get my results from the Database and echo it, print_r gives the right result.

```
ini_set('default_charset','utf-8');
header('Content-Type: text/plain; > charset=utf-8');
```

Firefox says char encode is utf-8 but if when i output:

```
print_r($listnew);
echo json_encode($listnew[5]);
```

print_r results everything right but json_encode does wrong.

print_r:

```
[5] => Array (
       [id] => 5
       [data] => U-Bahnhof Theresienstraße
       [size] => 17
)
```

json_encode:

> {"id":5,"data":"U-Bahnhof Theresienstra\u00dfe","size":17}

i know json_encode needs a utf-8 string to work properly there and i feel im having a encode trouble here but i just can't firgure out where it is.

Any help would be appreciated,

thanks in advance.

i3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ummm... I think that is the *correct* way actually. `\u00df` is a correct unicode representation of `ß`. When you `json_decode()` it back, it will become `ß`  again.

Where is this making problems for you? Is the receiving end not decoding it properly? It should if you use standard `json_*` functions.

All the examples in the [manual](http://www.php.net/json_encode) show the same thing - characters beyond the ASCII range are turned into numeric sequences.

Comment: I wasn't aware of the fact that it probably will be translated back by the decode, so i was tracking errors where are none. 

I just generate the Output, but i later don't process the json object, so probably it will be solved by the other application. 

Sorry and thanks for your help,

i3

Comment: Sometimes when encoding i use json_encode($array,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE )